# Executing a jar through ant clean dist- appears under different name?

Tags: java, hadoop, ant, jar, build.xml

I'm working with hadoop and need to create a .jar file combined from all of my classes in /src file. Everytime I try to create it it appears under WordCount.jar instead of Twitter.jar which I have stated in my code below:

```css
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class Twitter {
    public static void runJob(String[] input, String output) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(Twitter.class);
        job.setReducerClass(TwitterReducer.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TwitterMapper.class);
   
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);
        Path outputPath = new Path(output);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, StringUtils.join(input, ","));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
        outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath, true);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        runJob(Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 0, args.length - 1), args[args.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

Therefore I am unsure what is wrong? The files in the .jar itself are exactly the same as in /src folder.

Comment: Your class is called `Twitter` however this doesn't means that your `.jar` must have this name... the `.jar` name probably is defined in jar creation task in the `build.xml`. can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the Jar file has nothing to do the name of a class in it. You need to check the Ant buildfile, specifically the target that creates the jar. The Ant task that creates the Jar file is usually the [`jar`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) task and the name of the file can be specified via the `destfile` attribute.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that as it's the first time I ever worked with such kind of files! Worked, thanks!